# Office 365/Exchange Online Mail rule triggers twice when 2 internal recipients receive mail

Tags: email, office365, exchange-server, rules

I am having an issue where we have a rule set up to catch all mail coming in from a specific address and BCC the email off to 2 external addresses.

The rule is set up like this

```
If the message...
Is received from 'email@example.com'
Do the following...
Blind carbon copy(Bcc) the message to 'external@domain1.com' and 'external@domain2.com'
```

The email from email@example.com is sent from a web form and addressed to auser@mydomain.com and asharedmailbox@mydomain.com.

When the mail comes in, it is BCC'd twice to the external addresses and 1 copy only delivered locally in user and sharedmailbox.

This is all reflected in a message trace.

Has anyone come across this and knows how to prevent this?

TIA

Comment: Do you have that rule set up on both mailboxes `auser@mydomain.com` and `asharedmailbox@mydomain.com`?

Comment: Ah sorry should have clarified, the rule is not set up on the mailboxes, just in the exchange online backend.

EDIT: Sigh, one of the users set up a rule, I didn't think to look at their mailboxes...

EDIT2: Actually the rule they have is for items received before a date in January this year so would not be active.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else in my organisation found out how to work around this.

They added in a condition to the "If the message" operation as below

```
If the message...
Is sent to 'auser@mydomain.com'
And Is received from 'email@example.com'
Do the following...
Blind carbon copy(Bcc) the message to 'external@domain1.com' and 'external@domain2.com'
```

And now the rule only processed once.